# SQLite database, onUpgrade for version1 to release

Tags: android, database, sqlite

OK, so my app is ready for full release.  I want to prepare my SQLite db correctly for release.  My initial development program utilized the following code for onUpgrade (SQLite db helper class).

```
 @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Then, as I needed to update my database, I followed [this](https://thebhwgroup.com/blog/how-android-sqlite-onupgrade) tutorial to increase the revision numbers, add columns, and all worked very well.  For example, my onUpgrade changed to this.

```
    private static final String DATABASE_ALTER_ADD_VELOCITY = "ALTER TABLE walk_run_table ADD COLUMN VELOCITY_CALC REAL";

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (oldVersion < 2) db.execSQL(DATABASE_ALTER_ADD_VELOCITY);
        if (oldVersion < 3) db.execSQL(DATABASE_ALTER_ADD_ELEVATION);
    }
```

Now, I'm preparing for release and want to bring my version back down to 1 (since all users will be getting a fresh install of course).  Should my onUpgrade revert to "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS".... ?  And then proceed with revisions as shown in the tutorial mentioned earlier?  This worked well for me in development and I suspect will work well for release, but want to make sure for uploading my program to google play.  Is there a better practice to prepare the SQLite db for future revisions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter which actual version number you are using; it can go up to four billion.
And future app versions will have to increase the database version anyway; there's nothing gained by setting it to one now.

Your released app will never encounter an old database, so you can remove the code to update from older development versions.
If you do encounter a smaller version number, you have accidentally run it on a development machine, or the database file got corrupted, or someone copied a fake database into your application's storage. In all cases, the correct response is to error out.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are suggesting that I leave my code in "as developed" condition and release as revision 3. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. (Not that it really matters.)